# Why $\epsilon \aleph_0 =\epsilon$?

Tags: functional-analysis, elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, cardinals

Just a quick question. In the proof of Proposition. 4.14. in Conway's Functional Analysis, it states without any proof that if $E$ is any infinite set with cardinality $\epsilon$ then $\epsilon \aleph_0 =\epsilon$ holds, I just know the proof for special case $\epsilon = \aleph_0$ and not for $\epsilon= \aleph_1, ...$ and I know very little set theory. Please help!

Comment: This follows from the general fact* that if $\kappa$ and $\lambda$ are infinite cardinal numbers then $\kappa \lambda = \mathrm{max} \{ \kappa, \lambda \}$.$\\$
[*Assuming the axiom of choice, which I assume is just fine in the context of functional analysis!]

Comment: This follows from $n^2=n$ for infinite cardinal $n$ (assuming AC), the proof of which is essentially the same as the proof of $\aleph_0\times\aleph_0=\aleph_0$.

Comment: @CliveNewstead could you provide a reference easy to read with a proof for the statement you said?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I also don't know much set theory, so this may not be right.)

Once we know the fact that $\aleph_0^2 = \aleph_0$, we can generalize it to $\epsilon\aleph_0 = \epsilon$. Let $E$ be a set with cardinality $\epsilon$. We will show $|E| = |E \times \mathbb{N}|$. Clearly, $|E| \leq |E \times \mathbb{N}|$, so it remains to show the other direction.

First, divide $E$ into a family $\{E_i\}_{i \in I}$ where each $E_i$ is a countably infinite subset of $E$. Then for each $E_i$, there is an injective function $\phi_i : E_i \times \mathbb{N} \to E_i$. We can construct an injective function $\phi : E \times \mathbb{N} \to E$ where

$$
\phi(e, n) = \phi_i(e, n) \quad \text{for $e \in E_i$}.
$$

Therefore, $|E \times \mathbb{N}| \leq |E|$, and so we conclude $\epsilon\aleph_0 = \epsilon$.

Comment: You need each $E_i$ to be countably infinite. More importantly, how do you find or construct $\{E_i\}_{i \in I}$? - just assuming it exists is begging the question.

Comment: @DavidHartley You're right, $E_i$ does have to be countably infinite. And as for constructing $\{E_i\}_{i \in I}$, I guess you're right. I didn't think about it that deeply, but at a high level, it at least intuitively ought to be true.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $\epsilon$ is an initial ordinal. Each of its elements is equal to $\lambda + n$ for some  unique limit ordinal (or $0$) $\lambda$ and $n \in \mathbb N$. Let $\psi$ be a bijection $\mathbb N \times \mathbb N\to \mathbb N $. Then mapping $(\lambda + n, m) \mapsto \lambda + \psi(n,m)$ gives a bijection $\epsilon \times \mathbb N \to \epsilon$.

If you assume the Axiom of Choice, all infinite sets are equal in cardinality to some initial ordinal and so the result holds for all cardinals. Without choice it may fail, for example if $\epsilon$ is Dedekind finite then $\epsilon \aleph_0$ will be Dedekind infinite and so cannot equal